# Create a form to export Html file

Tags: javascript, css, html, html-email

I am looking to give my users several "feature" options to help write an html file for an email. I have the code I would like to use for each feature, but I want the user to be able to pick a feature (i.e. Hero Image Header > Title > Paragraph > Two column photos > Button > etc.) and then submit the content to send me an email with an html file built.

Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: What's the problem?

Comment: suggestions for what, exactly?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/form

Comment: Welcome to SO! Unfortunately this is too general of a question to be answerable here. StackOverflow isn't a forum, it's a question and answer site, which relies on specific questions involving code so that the answers may be easily referenced by others.

Comment: Need suggestions on what I could use for this type of output from a form or DND platform. I am essentially trying to give someone the option of "building their own email" but using prewritten code so that someone who does not know code can select the features and input the information needed. Then it would send an email to me with the completed html file.

Answer (score 0):

Hi @Pairtho if you don`t mind, if you still need a suggestion about your email template just comment below so that we can discuss.